# How can I get a tree view for large JSON files in PyCharm?

Tags: text-editors, pycharm, json

When I open a small JSON file in PyCharm, I can easily collapse or expand its sections (note the medal-shaped symbols on the left):

[image]

However, when I open a large JSON file, this isn't possible anymore (no medal-shaped symbols). PyCharm still seems to understand that this is a JSON file and it should be formatted as such, but the section collapsing capability is gone, which seriously hampers JSOn file editing:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Apparently, PyCharm complains that the file is too large and "code insight features" are not available, but I'm not sure whether these features have anything to do with the possibility of collapsing sections.

I'm using PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Professional Edition) on macOS 12.6 (Monterey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147946/15128124

Go to Help > Edit Custom Properties

Add:

idea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999

Restart the IDE.

---

see more:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2022.3/tuning-the-ide.html#common-platform-properties

idea.max.intellisense.filesize

Maximum size of files (in kilobytes) for which PyCharm provides coding assistance. Coding assistance for large files can affect editor performance and increase memory consumption. The default value is 2500.